# Apollo GraphQL local and global error handling

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using Apollo to interact with a GraphQL server in a Web application written in React. I'm trying to implement error handling in the application and relying on [apollo-link-error](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error.html) for this.

Now, there are 2 categories of errors that I need to handle:

1. errors that can be handled locally in the component which does the Apollo query or mutation, i.e. an invalid form field on which I need to show contextual error information
2. errors that can be handled globally, for example by showing a toast notification displaying error details somewhere in the page

Clearly, once the error is handled locally I need it to **not** be handled globally, because it doesn't make much sense to show an error message next to a form field *and* a generic error via a toast message.

The first stumbling block I encountered when trying to implement this is that the global error handling logic triggers **before** the local error handling logic, which prevents me from being able to intercept the error locally and then find a way to prevent the global logic from kicking in.

I created codesandbox example which sets up an `ApolloClient` in the simplest possible way, uses the http and error links, and uses the `react-apollo` `Query` component to do a query for a resource that doesn't exist, generating an error.

I'm handling the error both in the `onError` callback of the `Query` component (so local error handling), and in the `apollo-link-error` handler (so global error handling), and printing to the console the errors.

[image: console output]

It shows that the global error handling logic kicks in before the local error handling. I would need it to be the other way around.

[image: Edit apollo error handling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've published a library called [react-apollo-network-status](https://github.com/molindo/react-apollo-network-status) which handles exactly this use case. Let me know if it's useful to you!

The opt-in/-out behaviour for treating some errors locally is implemented by setting a context variable on the operation which can be read in the error link.